# Using different media stylesheets together with a print stylesheet

Tags: html, css, web, printing, stylesheet

I have a school assignment that I can't for the life of me figure out. We've been asked to explain the difference between the two following ways of linking a print stylesheet along with a different stylesheet in HTML, and explain in which situations we would use which technique:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen” />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print” />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="all” />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print” />
```

Can someone please give me a pointer as to how screen and all are different when it comes to using them together with a separate print stylesheet?

Comment: Welcome to SO....unfortunately we don't do homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to do your homework, but feeling your pain. media="screen" makes that link statement only apply to the screen HTML. Remember there are many types of media, so specifying media="screen" limits it. Media="all" is the default and will apply to all not specified or overridden otherwise.